# tabla SQL, al llamarla en php me muestra datos, pero al usar condicional WHERE no me da resultados

Tags: php, sql

soy nuevo en esto y primero gracias!! he aprendido muchísimo con sus respuestas a otros post!, mi problema es que tengo una base de datos en sql, la tabla se llama ktronix, la primera columna "title", y en php cuando llamo los datos sin condicional me muestra todos los datos sin problema hasta ahí, pero al usar Where seguido de la variable que viene de mi (input) de búsqueda deja de mostrarme resultados mi codigo es sencillo va así:

```
<?php
    if ($busqueda = $_GET["q"]);
    echo $busqueda;
    ?>
<br>
<?php 
if (!isset($busqueda)){ 
      echo "Debe especificar una busqueda"; 
      echo "</html></body> \n"; 
      exit; 
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ktronix`";
mysqli_select_db($db ,"pruebas"); 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo "title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
}
     }
?>
```

[image: sin condicional]

este código me da todos los resultados de la tabla, todo bien hasta ahí, pero cuando uso:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "$sql WHERE `title` LIKE '%.$busqueda.%'");
```

no muestra nada!, el "echo" de la variable `$busqueda` si es lo que solicito en el `input`, entonces no creo que sea esa variable, he intentado con comillas dobles, paréntesis, creo que de todas las formas que se me han ocurrido para ( `WHERE`title`LIKE '%.$busqueda.%'` ) también ubiqué esto en la variable de la tabla (`$sql`) y nada, también use una constante escribiendo directamente TV, =tv, =%tv, etc, en lugar de `$busqueda`...nada

[image: con condicional]

agradezco si alguien me saca de la duda de que estoy haciendo mal!, muchas gracias por sus comentarios y ayuda!, saludos

Comment: La consulta tiene que quedar así: **`$sql="SELECT * FROM ktronix WHERE tile LIKE '%$busqueda%'";`** **Los puntos que hay después y antes de `%` tienes que quitarlos.** Para salir de dudas, pruébala primero en la BD directamente escrita a mano, cambiando `$busqueda` por un valor cualquiera. Ten en cuenta que si la columna es *case sensitive*, no te reconocerá como iguales los valores `TV` y `tv`

Comment: hola , muchas gracias por tu respuesta , funciono con '%".$busqueda."%'"

Comment: Así también debería funcionar: `$sql="SELECT * FROM ktronix WHERE tile LIKE '%$busqueda%'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si de todos modos deseas concatenar la variable dentro de tu consulta, deberías proceder de este modo:

```
'%".$busqueda."%'
```

- La variable queda concatenada entre los puntos `.`
- Usas la sintaxis de **comillasimple-comilladoble** y para finalizar **comilladoble-comillasimple**
- Sin embargo el uso de los *wildcars* colócalos entre los juegos de comillas simples y dobles de este modo: `'%"...aqui la variable...."%'`

Tu consulta quedaría así:

```
$busqueda = "valor";
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `ktronix` WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$busqueda."%'");
```

Comment: No hay por qué complicarse, la consulta puede quedar escrita así: **`"SELECT * FROM ktronix WHERE title LIKE '%$busqueda%'"`**

Comment: Lo sé @A.Cedano  solo quería mostrarle como lograr lo que trataba de hacer concatenando la variable

Comment: me funciono perfecto el problema era '%".$busqueda."%'" y la ubicación de los puntos, comillas y porcentajes, mil gracias!